# is there a connection between the following?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $A$ is $m \times n$ and $B$ is $m \times n$.

Is there a connection between the eigenvalues of $AB'$ and the eigenvalues of $B'A$?

One is an $m \times m$ and the other is $n \times n$.

($B'$ stands for the transpose of $B$)

Comment: Have you tried a small case, say, $m=1$, $n=2$, to see what happens?

Comment: Using block matrices, we can see that $\sigma(AB^t)\setminus \{0\}=\sigma(B^tA)\setminus \{0\}$. We have a relationship of the form $\det(XI_m-AB^t)X^n=\det(XI_n-B^tA)$.

Comment: @Gerry I am embarrassed to say I have just tried it a bit, and the singular values seem to be the same, like Davide claims, I think, for the general case. Is there a way to see it (for the general case)?

Comment: I missed a $X^m$ in the last comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems easier for me to assume that $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix. In that case, [a classical argument](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31595/how-would-you-solve-this-tantalizing-halmos-problem) shows that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues, not counting multiplicity. The case that these eigenvalues are distinct is dense in the general case, so $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues counting multiplicity. Of course one of them has $|n-m|$ more zero eigenvalues than the other.